# Script export duplicate item after N repeated times

Tags: bash, awk, count

Write bash script and encounter small issue,
So im writing repatable in Log.txt file :

```
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
20201002 105710 000500000475FB8E dummy1
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
20201002 105710 000500000475FB8E dummy1
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
```

and trying to get information of line text which has been repeated more then 6 times.

with sort i can see which it
but there i got few issues. if creating extra space in front or line

```
$ sort Log.txt | uniq -cd | sort -nr
      6 20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
      2 20201002 105710 000500000475FB8E dummy1
```

I have done something like:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 source ~/.bash_profile
  3
  4 
  5 fileLog='Log.txt'
  6
  7
  8 i="0"
  9 lines=`sort $fileLog | uniq -cd | sort -nr |wc -l`
 10 dublines=`sort $fileLog | uniq -cd | sort -nr `
 11
 12 while ($i < "$lines");
 13 do
 14         check=`cat $dublines | awk ""NR==$i"" | cut -d' ' -f'7' `
 15         i=$[$i+1]
 16         if (("$check" >= "6"));
 17                 then
 18                 limited=`cat $dublines | awk ""NR==$i""`
 19                 echo "$limited"
 20         fi
 21 done
```

Result what im want to get is like :

```
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
```

but bash -x showing:

```
+ fileLog=Log.txt
+ i=0
++ uniq -cd
++ sort -nr
++ sort Log.txt
++ wc -l
+ lines=2
++ uniq -cd
++ sort -nr
++ sort Log.txt
+ dublines='      6 20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
      2 20201002 105710 000500000475FB8E dummy1'
+ 0
script.sh: line 12: 2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: change `while ($i < "$lines")` to `while (($i < "$lines"))`, just like `if (("$check" >= "6"))` in your code.

Comment: You should not use a bash loop to read a file line by line, especially a large file. This can be extremely slow, in case you call commands for every line. Here you raise many system processes for every line. Use one process to read the whole file. For text-processing, use one grep, awk, sed, python script, perl script, do not call them once for every line but once for the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using combination of `sort`,`uniq` and `awk`:

```
sort Log.txt |uniq -c|awk '{if ($1 == "6") for(i=2; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s ", $i;print " "}'
```

Output:

```
20201002 105646 000500000475FB8D dummy
```

Comment: I have solved my issue with this one,
but and awk " '++seen[$0]==6' file " worked

Answer (score 1):

Parse the file unsorted with one awk command:

```
awk '++seen[$0]==6' file
```

It will print once every line that appears 6 times or more.